# VW Golf MkV spoiler removal

Tags: vw, golf, body-work

I need to change the rear spoiler on my 2005 golf gti.

I read that it's possible to remove the adhesive by cutting through it with some kind of a thread, I guess nylon would be best.

Has anyone done this? Any tips?

Answer (score 3):

If you can work it under the spoiler, dental floss would probably work.  That will take care of the adhesive and it should come off if there aren't any bolts holding it on.

**Update**

I've never done this myself, but on the make/model specific forums I frequent, I've seen dental floss and fishing line recommended.  Though going back and searching, it seems the dental floss (doubled over) was recommended for emblems, fishing line for spoilers.  You might also try a gentle application of heat to loosen the adhesive, perhaps also (again, gently) applying a plastic putty knife once you've got enough of a gap opened up.  Make sure there aren't any bolts holding it on, check from below.  Though if you work fishing line from the driver side to the passenger side that should rule out any fasteners.

Comment: Spray the dental floss with WD40. The oils make the floss cut rather than pull the adhesive.

Comment: The dental floss isn't strong enough. Maybe I should try a fishing line? :/

Comment: I read somewhere else that it will slide up or down (can't remember) after removing the adhesive on each side.

Comment: I solved the problem. I will post a video soon.

Answer (score 1):

If the fishing line doesn't work try fishing leaders. Fishing leaders are available that are made of small diameter steel cable. It is available in measured  lengths or by the spool. They come in various strengths and are nylon coated which should protect the paint. I have used them to cut thru windshield adhesive. Park the car in the sun for a couple of hours to help soften the adhesive. Use a sawing action and lube the wire with WD40. Once everything starts to separate place small wooden wedges under the spoiler so it won't readhere.

Answer (score 0):

I totally forgot about this, but in case anyone has this problem, what did it for me was a plastic putty knife and a rubber sledge. Placing the tip of the knife on the adhesive and tapping it with the sledge; not in the middle of the blob but at the sides, letting the corner of the knife cut into it, slowly working my way to the center on each pass.

If you slide the knife under the spoiler on each end you can easily find where the blobs are.

F.Y.I. Any attempts with fishing line or dental floss were futile.